# unexpected stop working error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

When I add a website in to the project showing this error :

"problem caused the program to stop working correctly. windows will close the program and notify you solution"

here is what I did :

1. add new website, from File > Add > New Website
2. Choose the C# template, web location = HTTP > localhost
3. Error Appears...

Comment: Did you check **EventLog** for any errors?

Comment: No, Where can I find it ?

Comment: EventLog is a windows application which provides you with additional informations on what errors/infos aso occured within your system. On Win7 just hit Windows-Key type eventlog and start it. Windows-Logs - Application - within this look out for any entries from VS

Comment: Windows version, VS version, IIS version and edition, are you (Local) Admin ?

Comment: working on Win8 , VS 2010, IIS ver8 , and Yes.